# schema validate xml containing boolean values

Tags: xml, validation, schema

Hi I have a xml like this:

```
<xml><fullname>
<name attrib="true"/>
<lastname1 attrib="false"/>
<lastname2 attrib="false"/></fullname></xml>
```

I need to create a schema to validate it in such a way that it will allow only 1 attrib with value "true" (and the rest of them must be false [the attrib attribute is defined to be xs:boolean]), so i added a unique check in the element fullname like this:

```
   <xs:unique name="attribcheck">
<xs:selector xpath="name|lastname1|lastname2"/>
<xs:field xpath="@attrib"/>
```

Of course, it will detect that there is a duplicated "true", but also, it will detect a duplicated "false".
Does anyone know if there is a way to set a restriction on which value to apply the unique constraint? meaning that i can ensure that only one of them is "true" at any given time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XML Schema 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) does not support co-occurrence constraints - you cannot express a condition on one element based on the value of another.

This will change in [XML Schema 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions), but the latter is only in draft stage and is still changing, and will not be widely implemented for some time.

However, if you use [Saxon 9.2](http://www.saxonica.com), it has preliminary support for XML Schema 1.1 now.  See the [feature grid](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html) to determine which version is needed for schema validation.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i'll try to use the preliminary support for schema 1.1